# How to handle common errors (which can raise in every UIViewController in a single place) in a single place in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have many UIViewControlers in a client/server application. At any moment (on each screen) server could send general error, like wrong protocol sequence, deserialization error and etc. Is there a way to handle this errors in AppDelegate for example and show certain message and segue to certain screen, depending on the error?

Currently when I receive the error I send event which is handled by AppDelegate and it finds top most UIViewController and show Alert message. The problems are:
1. I want to segue to specific GeneralErrorsViewController, in order to stop processing anything until the error is resolved or just stop and give user a choice depending on the errors
2. When I show the message, if there is pending segue action, it switches to next UIViewController and the message is lost.

Comment: What are you using for fetching data from server? `NSURLConnection`? or some library like `AFNetworking`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no in built way of handling errors in one common place. I hope you realize that this makes sense because the system is not going to know what types of errors you want to handle and whether you want all of them handled the same way or differently, say alert for high priority errors only etc. Also, each view controller initiates different workflows and hence should have their own way of coping with errors. For example if you are making a web service call in a background process, you may not want to show the errors from that process when user is halfway through an important financial transaction where as its would be okay to show the error from a general home/settings screen etc.

So, handling errors within the app as per your requirement is your responsibility.

As you want a common way of handling errors, you can create a base view controller with a default method for handling errors and inherit all your other view controllers from it. Even better, create a protocol (interface) declaring all error handling methods and create a custom UIVeiwController and UITableViewController which implement these methods in the default way you want.
You can the inherit all your view controllers and table view controllers from the base classes.

I would recommend not using a 'segue' for showing the view controller in the base classes as all your view controllers are not going to have that segue. Instead, instantiate your GeneralErrorsViewController using it's storyboard id, check if the calling view controller has a non-nil navigation controller and push it onto the stack. If navigation controller is nil, show it modally.

This approach gives you two advantages. 1. The error handling is centralized like you want. 2. If your app requirements demand a screen which does not handle errors to handles them in some other way, you can either not inherit it from the base class or inherit and override the protocol methods to suit your needs.

Each vc can call it's own error handling methods when it faces an error. However, if you want to continue using your way of sending out an event (notification) in case of an error, you can register for these notifications in base vc's `viewWillAppear' and deregister in`viewWillDisappear` and call the protocol method from the notification handler and pass the error (which you can pass as an object along with the error notification) to the protocol method. This way you do not need to handle anything in app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

may  be u have to use **Try Catch** tyo Handle Error,

> Like below Example

```
   CabCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CabCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //Set Button Image

        @try {
            [cell.btnCell setImageForState:UIControlStateNormal withURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[dictBookPagelist[@"data"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:Param_vLogo]]];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"%@", exception.reason);
        }
        @finally {

            UIImageView *imageview=[UIImageView new];
            [imageview setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[dictBookPagelist[@"data"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:Param_vLogo]] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
            [cell.btnCell setImage:imageview.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
```